# Rotate object while following a path segment

Tags: animation

I have an object following a path. I want this object to start and stop rotating at two specific points of this path. I could insert 2 keyframes normally, but I'm guessing that this could be done in a more general way?

Specifically, later on I will want to replicate this object many times changing the trajectories randomly within a window. And all of them should start the rotation when crossing an imaginary plane (say x=2), and stopping when crossing a second imaginary plane (say x=4).

(I am new to blender. Any suggestion or idea about where to start would be much appreciated)

Comment: So that all trajectories would share the start and end point?

Comment: The starting point of all the trajectories is shared (x=0,y=0,z=0). The end point will be different in 3D (but same in the x axes; x=6). But the segment with rotation will be in-between this points (from x=2 to x=4).

Comment: I can try to develop the animation of the different trajectories first. But there are different ways to do this, and only some of them will be compatible with the "rotation activated in a region". So I was hoping that you the experts could give me some advice @Lukasz-40sth

Answer (score 1):

How to do this depends on the details of what you're doing, and how you want to specify the points measuring rotational changes.  I like to use a follow path on "fixed position" mode, and then animate the offset factor of the constraint.  If you're doing it this way, you can create a driver that interpolates between two different rotations on the basis of the offset:

[image]

I give Suzanne a follow path, on fixed position mode.  I create two empties with the same constraint, then use their *offset* to place them along the curve.  (Not by just translating them!)

Then, Suzanne gets two copy rotation constraints (world->world), targeting each empty.  The second constraint gets a driver for its influence.

I need three variables for this driver: the offset of each empty and the offset of Suzanne herself.  To create this driver, I can right click on Suzanne's second copy rotation influence and select "Create new driver".  Then, in the driver editor sidebar, with this driver selected, I can delete the starting variable and change the driver to a scripted expression.  To get each variable I actually want, I can right click in the offset field for each object and select "copy as new driver".  Then I can use the paste button (the second button to the right of "add input variable" in the driver sidebar) to paste these inputs into my driver.

After that, I set up my scripted expression.  I'm measuring the distance Suzanne has along the line, rescaled to the position of my first empty, rescaled to the length between the empties; I'm then using min() and max() functions to clamp this to the 0,1 range for the influence of the constraint.

Copy rotation doesn't always give you the interpolation you expect between 0 and 1. It's not wrong, it's just that 3D rotation interpolation is a more complicated beast than one at first assumes.  If you have problems with the interpolation of the rotation, there are other constraints you can use instead.

This gives you a tunable structure, where you can control the start and stop of the rotations, the length of the curve, and the exact rotations, all independent of each other.

Comment: thank you very much. This is much more detailed than I expected. I will work to implement your solution these days and post any follow-up comments if necesary